# Get count of requests within specified interval of time from log file

Tags: bash, awk

I need to get a count of requests in 1, 2 , 3, ..., *N* minutes via awk for a log file.

For example, the user sets a variable which corresponds to one minute intervals (`$interval=1`) – the output should be like

```
09:01 - 09:02  
count of requests 
09:02 - 09:03
count of requests
 ... 
09:16 - 09:17 
count of requests
```

For an interval of 2 minutes:

```
09:01 - 09:03 
count of requests
09:03 - 09:05
count of requests
...
09:15 - 09:17
count of requests
```

I have tried to solve the assigned task via bash script, but it works only for one minute intervals:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=1; i<=17 ;i++))
do
        echo "in $i interval"
        if [[ "$i" -lt 10 ]] ;then
                 awk "/2015:09:0$i.*/" access_log | awk 'END{print NR}'
        else
                 awk "/2015:09:$i.*/" access_log | awk 'END{print NR}'
        fi
done
```

Sample of input lines;

```
10.1.2.194 (207.46.13.7, 54.239.137.128) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:01:42 +0000] "GET /merlin-image-server/view/756af03a-6dc4-4568-9081-0b6f48d2f9d5/120 HTTP/1.1" 200 2944 0 100220 "-" "Amazon CloudFront" "ajp://10.1.3.202:8009"
10.1.2.194 (78.192.164.23) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:01:42 +0000] "GET /merlin-web-za/cb3c50fb8011691d674f6df81d57e2a7e/web/img/search/serp-bg.png HTTP/1.1" 200 6986 0 1772 "http://www.autotrader.co.za/merlin-web-za/bundles/css/N943289621/bundle.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36" "ajp://10.1.4.17:8009"
10.1.2.194 (78.192.164.23) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:01:42 +0000] "GET /merlin-web-za/cbad2541a0cf556c96fd6dd70a692636c3/web/images/search/counter.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0 1517 "http://www.autotrader.co.za/makemodel/make/mercedes-benz/model/s-class/search" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36" "ajp://10.1.4.17:8009"
10.1.2.194 (78.192.164.23) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:01:42 +0000] "GET /merlin-web-za/cb9ddf6600496d51326b3b02718fd8d1da/web/img/global/new.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0 1301 "http://www.autotrader.co.za/makemodel/make/mercedes-benz/model/s-class/search" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36" "ajp://10.1.4.17:8009"
10.1.2.194 (78.192.164.23) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:01:42 +0000] "GET /merlin-web-za/web/images/refinements/loader.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 4178 0 1652 "http://www.autotrader.co.za/makemodel/make/mercedes-benz/model/s-class/search" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36" "ajp://10.1.4.17:8009"
10.1.2.194 (196.11.233.81) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:01:42 +0000] "GET /merlin-web-za/web/images/search/watchlist-error-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 200 429 0 1631 "http://www.autotrader.co.za/seoregion/kwazulu-natal/makemodel/make/volkswagen/model/polo/bodytype/hatchback/search?sort=PriceAsc&county=KwaZulu-Natal&longitude=31.0292&locationName=Durban&latitude=-29.8579&pageNumber=22" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36" "ajp://10.1.3.86:8009"
10.1.2.194 (196.15.160.44) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:06:26 +0000] "GET /merlin-web-za/bundles/js/935688859/bundle.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0 1476 "http://www.autotrader.co.za/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/85-000-to-99-999/transmissiontype/automatic/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/100-000-to-124-999/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/125-000-to-149-999/search?pageNumber=29" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.5 Safari/537.36" "ajp://10.1.3.88:8009"
10.1.2.194 (196.15.160.44) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:06:26 +0000] "GET /merlin-web-za/bundles/css/N943289621/bundle.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0 1297 "http://www.autotrader.co.za/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/85-000-to-99-999/transmissiontype/automatic/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/100-000-to-124-999/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/125-000-to-149-999/search?pageNumber=29" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.5 Safari/537.36" "ajp://10.1.3.88:8009"
10.1.2.194 (54.77.132.130) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:06:26 +0000] "GET /merlin-service-search/rest/featuresbyatmmv?atmmvcode=7799 HTTP/1.1" 200 6249 0 10193 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1" "ajp://10.1.4.67:8009"
10.1.2.194 (66.249.91.222) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:06:26 +0000] "GET /makemodel/make/OPEL/model/ASTRA/bodytype/Hatchback/search?pageNumber=4 HTTP/1.1" 301 20 0 1860 "-" "Mediapartners-Google" "ajp://10.1.3.203:8009"
10.1.2.194 (197.77.174.86) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:06:26 +0000] "GET /merlin-service-search/rest/dblastupdatetime HTTP/1.1" 200 25 0 2083 "-" "-" "ajp://10.1.3.204:8009"
10.1.2.194 (66.85.139.244, 216.137.44.16) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:06:26 +0000] "GET /merlin-image-server/view/118e4e83-a621-44f1-8c85-8a2e95145055/800 HTTP/1.1" 200 72634 0 89903 "-" "Amazon CloudFront" "ajp://10.1.3.202:8009"
10.1.2.194 (54.246.139.111) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:06:26 +0000] "GET /merlin-service-search/rest/featuresbyatmmv?atmmvcode=27749 HTTP/1.1" 200 70 0 7872 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1" "ajp://10.1.3.86:8009"
10.1.2.194 (54.246.139.111) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:06:26 +0000] "GET /merlin-service-search/rest/featuresbyatmmv?atmmvcode=27753 HTTP/1.1" 200 4267 0 11619 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1" "ajp://10.1.3.205:8009"
10.1.2.194 (54.77.132.130) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:11:48 +0000] "GET /merlin-service-search/rest/featuresbyatmmv?atmmvcode=11867 HTTP/1.1" 200 348 0 10677 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1" "ajp://10.1.3.202:8009"
10.1.2.194 (54.77.132.130) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:11:48 +0000] "GET /merlin-service-search/rest/featuresbyatmmv?atmmvcode=17267 HTTP/1.1" 200 3266 0 7127 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1" "ajp://10.1.4.17:8009"
10.1.2.194 (41.208.251.58, 54.240.147.15) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:11:48 +0000] "GET /merlin-image-server/view/916e54c2-2b4a-40b2-8f41-4a0dc8ec0b0e/220 HTTP/1.1" 200 8555 0 111773 "-" "Amazon CloudFront" "ajp://10.1.4.68:8009"
10.1.2.194 (197.77.1.243, 54.240.147.77) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:11:48 +0000] "GET /merlin-image-server/view/8cfd5e47-7d5d-45f6-8380-3276e2c4d552/650 HTTP/1.1" 200 70044 0 164335 "-" "Amazon CloudFront" "ajp://10.1.3.202:8009"
10.1.2.194 (196.26.128.178) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:11:48 +0000] "GET /merlin-web-za/web/images/fav.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 643 0 881 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko" "ajp://10.1.4.67:8009"
10.1.2.194 (196.22.229.4) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:11:48 +0000] "GET /merlin-web-za/bundles/css/N943289621/bundle.css HTTP/1.1" 200 39605 0 13377 "http://www.autotrader.co.za/makemodel/make/AUDI/model/A1/neworused/new/search" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36" "ajp://10.1.3.88:8009"
10.1.2.194 (105.210.54.155) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:11:48 +0000] "GET /merlin-web-za/bundles/css/N943289621/bundle.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0 918 "http://www.autotrader.co.za/neworused/used/fueltype/petrol/makemodel/make/toyota/model/yaris/makemodel/make/nissan/model/hardbody/model/np300-hardbody/search?sort=PriceAsc" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36" "ajp://10.1.4.70:8009"
10.1.2.194 (197.79.11.175) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:11:48 +0000] "GET /used-cars/land-rover/freelander-2/2007-land-rover-freelander-2-s-i6-gezina-fpa-8a81839749ae76d9014a4e672e347fe2 HTTP/1.1" 200 30154 0 101659 "http://www.autotrader.co.za/makemodel/make/LAND%20ROVER/model/FREELANDER%202/search?&pageNumber=9" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-gb; GT-N7100 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30" "ajp://10.1.4.66:8009"
10.1.2.194 (41.189.79.130) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:11:48 +0000] "GET /merlin-web-za/web/images/fav.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 894 0 1400 "http://www.autotrader.co.za/makemodel/make/jeep/model/wrangler/caryearrangeszar/2015/search?keywords=unlimited&sort=PriceAsc&gquery=null" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36" "ajp://10.1.3.205:8009"
10.1.2.194 (41.13.72.175) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:11:48 +0000] "GET /merlin-web-za/cb161f2003381435a3347b2603bfd9fa5d/mobile/images/gr.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 413 0 1310 "http://www.autotrader.co.za/makemodel/make/OPEL/model/COMBO/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/under-10000/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/10000-to-24999/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/25000-to-39999/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/40000-to-54999/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/55000-to-69999/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/70000-to-84999/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/85000-to-99999/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/100000-to-124999/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/125000-to-149999/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/150000-to-174999/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/175000-to-199999/search" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; SM-A500F Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.534 Mobile Safari/537.36" "ajp://10.1.3.205:8009"
10.1.2.194 (196.210.212.56) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:11:48 +0000] "GET /merlin-web-za/cbad2541a0cf556c96fd6dd70a692636c3/web/images/search/counter.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0 576 "http://www.autotrader.co.za/makemodel/make/SUZUKI/model/SWIFT/search?pageNumber=7" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36" "ajp://10.1.4.15:8009"
10.1.2.194 (41.13.72.175) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:11:48 +0000] "GET /merlin-web-za/cb53aec1b9de3d5953ed77f3979a4cb960/mobile/images/green.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 1009 0 1339 "http://www.autotrader.co.za/makemodel/make/OPEL/model/COMBO/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/under-10000/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/10000-to-24999/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/25000-to-39999/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/40000-to-54999/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/55000-to-69999/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/70000-to-84999/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/85000-to-99999/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/100000-to-124999/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/125000-to-149999/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/150000-to-174999/carandcommercialpricerangeszar/175000-to-199999/search" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; SM-A500F Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.534 Mobile Safari/537.36" "ajp://10.1.3.205:8009"
10.1.2.194 (41.160.30.18, 54.240.147.15) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:11:48 +0000] "GET /merlin-image-server/view/1f5d62d6-a303-4a86-9500-a726e260d845/120 HTTP/1.1" 200 2275 0 53108 "-" "Amazon CloudFront" "ajp://10.1.4.68:8009"
10.1.2.194 (207.46.13.7) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:11:48 +0000] "GET /used-commercial-vehicles/isuzu/npr/1980-isuzu-spr-422-5-ton-port-elizabeth-cfpa-8aa3054c44b1c9500144df47c82e51a2/seoregion/eastern-cape/makemodel/make/isuzu HTTP/1.1" 301 20 0 19664 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)" "ajp://10.1.3.204:8009"
10.1.2.194 (54.77.132.130) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:14:43 +0000] "GET /merlin-service-search/rest/featuresbyatmmv?atmmvcode=15395 HTTP/1.1" 200 1296 0 9272 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1" "ajp://10.1.3.201:8009"
10.1.2.194 (41.222.51.122, 54.239.183.6) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:14:43 +0000] "GET /merlin-image-server/view/3070c6d7-00b6-4186-b884-a19133ea3a97/200 HTTP/1.1" 200 6267 0 58404 "-" "Amazon CloudFront" "ajp://10.1.4.70:8009"
10.1.2.194 (196.4.0.2, 54.240.157.43) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:14:43 +0000] "GET /merlin-image-server/view/997e28de-6ea4-401d-8960-f28d55675c43/60 HTTP/1.1" 200 1312 0 93228 "-" "Amazon CloudFront" "ajp://10.1.4.66:8009"
10.1.2.194 (41.222.51.122, 54.239.183.52) - - [08/Oct/2015:09:14:43 +0000] "GET /merlin-image-server/view/0685c8e8-2e66-4f27-8ff3-4e45ebaccf6f/200 HTTP/1.1" 200 6359 0 74447 "-" "Amazon CloudFront" "ajp://10.1.3.88:8009"
```

See the whole file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zxDpOxz6pGf_veXBcbO_G1OyBENcwpKu).

Comment: IMHO, try to put dummy IP addresses in your samples in case you have not done that.

Comment: You can't solve this using regular expressions in a reasonable way, if the interval is larger than 1 minute! You need to do time/date arithmetic here, which makes awk a poor choice for the task.

Comment: @user1934428 thanks for feedback. do you know any other way to solve problem? using awk is
not necessary.

Comment: Any language with good date arithmetic would do. I would use Ruby, but Perl or Python should work too. After all, you need to calculate the time period between two points in time to solve your problem. Also drop bash - you use bash only to loop through the file, and for each line start a separate child process. Doesn't make that much sense.

Comment: I'll post a simple solution using `date` in `bash` in a few minutes. Can you update the sample snippet to include hits from more than one minute?

Comment: @PaulHodges updated, btw you can download full file the link is below the sample.

Comment: There's a couple of things that aren't clear in your question: 1) with an interval of 1 minutes, should something that occurs at 09:04 precisely be counted in the 09:03 - 09:04 bucket or the 09:04 to 09:05 bucket or both? 2) Should the output list all of the times from the earliest to the latest in "interval" increments or only list the ones that have values present? Please update your sample input/output to cover those cases.

Comment: @EdMorton can u please attach some explanations of parsing string in your sample (|line 4,5)  it's not clear.

Comment: You should post comments about an answer under the answer you're commenting on, not under your question, so the context for your comment is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're requirements aren't clear in a couple of areas (see my comment under your question) but here's the general approach using GNU awk for time functions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[][]" }
{
    split($2,t,/[\/: ]/)
    t[2] = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",t[2])+2)/3
    epochMins = int(mktime(t[3] " " t[2] " " t[1] " " t[4] " " t[5] " 0") / 60)
    if (NR == 1) {
        begMins = epochMins
    }
    endMins = epochMins
    cnt[epochMins]++
}
END {
    for (epochMins = begMins; epochMins <= endMins; epochMins+=interval) {
        begTime = strftime("%H:%M",epochMins*60)
        endTime = strftime("%H:%M",(epochMins+interval)*60)
        tot = 0
        begInterval = epochMins
        endInterval = epochMins + interval - 1
        for (i=begInterval; i<=endInterval; i++) {
            tot += cnt[i]
        }
        print begTime, endTime ORS tot
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v interval=1 -f tst.awk file
09:01 09:02
6
09:02 09:03
0
09:03 09:04
0
09:04 09:05
0
09:05 09:06
0
09:06 09:07
8
09:07 09:08
0
09:08 09:09
0
09:09 09:10
0
09:10 09:11
0
09:11 09:12
14
09:12 09:13
0
09:13 09:14
0
09:14 09:15
4
```

.

```
$ awk -v interval=2 -f tst.awk file
09:01 09:03
6
09:03 09:05
0
09:05 09:07
8
09:07 09:09
0
09:09 09:11
0
09:11 09:13
14
09:13 09:15
4
```

.

```
$ awk -v interval=5 -f tst.awk file
09:01 09:06
6
09:06 09:11
8
09:11 09:16
18
```

Comment: In response to [your comment under your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59250376/get-count-of-requests-within-specified-interval-of-time-from-log-file/59257014#comment104751848_59250376), line 4 `(index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",t[2])+2)/3` is the idiomatic way to convert a month name (e.g. Mar) to the number (3). Just think about what it's doing and add some `prints` for intermediate steps if it's not obvious. Line 5 is just calling mktime() to convert a timestamp to seconds since the epoch and then converting that to mins. See mktime in the gawk man page.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it's a little kludgy and runs `date` on every line of the file, and `read` *twice* (ugh), but try something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
declare -i interval=${1:- 1} timestamp=0 elapsed=0 last=0 cnt=0
declare H M lh lm                                              # reporting vars
echo "Counting hits per ${interval}m interval"
interval=$(( interval * 60 ))                                  # convert to seconds
while IFS="][" read x d x && [[ -n "$d" ]]                     # pull just the the timestamp
do IFS="$IFS/:" read day mon year h m s x <<< "$d"             # parse components
   timestamp="$( date -d "$mon $day $year $h:$m:$s" +'%s' )"   # reformat to epoch secs
   if (( last ))
   then elapsed="$(( timestamp - last ))"                      # check elapsed time since last
        if (( elapsed > interval ))
        then printf "$H:$M - $lh:$lm\n$cnt\n"
             cnt=1
             last=$timestamp
             H=$h; M=$m;
             lh=$h; lm=$m;
        else cnt+=1
             lh=$h; lm=$m;
        fi
   else last=$timestamp                                        # assure initialized
        H=$h; M=$m;
        lh=$h; lm=$m;
        cnt=1
   fi
done < "$yourLogFile" # you'll need to set this
printf "$H:$M - $lh:$lm\n$cnt\n"
```

When the minute changes it checks to see if the interval has been exceeded, and reports the count if it has.

```
$: ./tst
Counting hits per 1m interval
09:01 - 09:01
6
09:06 - 09:06
8
09:11 - 09:11
14
09:14 - 09:14
4

$: ./tst 3
Counting hits per 3m interval
09:01 - 09:01
6
09:06 - 09:06
8
09:11 - 09:14
18

$: ./tst 7
Counting hits per 7m interval
09:01 - 09:06
14
09:11 - 09:14
18
```

That ought to get your started.

---

A crude all-`awk` version -

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

awk -v interval=${1:- 1} '
BEGIN { last = 0; cnt = 0;
   printf "Counting hits per %sm interval\n", interval
   interval = interval * 60
}

/:/ {
  split( $0,     tmp,  "[" )
  split( tmp[2], t2,   "]" )
  split( t2[1],  tmp,  ":" ) # tmp  now date, H, M, S, tz
  H = tmp[2]; M = tmp[3]
  split( tmp[1], dtmp, "/" ) # dtmp now dd, Mon, yyyy
  switch ( dtmp[2] ) {
   case "Jan": Mon = "01"; break; case "Feb": Mon = "02"; break; case "Mar": Mon = "03"; break;
   case "Apr": Mon = "04"; break; case "May": Mon = "05"; break; case "Jun": Mon = "06"; break;
   case "Jul": Mon = "07"; break; case "Aug": Mon = "08"; break; case "Sep": Mon = "09"; break;
   case "Oct": Mon = "10"; break; case "Nov": Mon = "11"; break; case "Dec": Mon = "12"; break;
  }
  tstr = sprintf( "%s %s %s %s %s %s", dtmp[3], Mon, dtmp[1], H, M, "00" )
  epoch = mktime( tstr )

  if ( last ) {
     elapsed = epoch - last
     if ( elapsed > interval ) {
        printf "%s:%s - %s:%s\n%s\n", h, m, lh, lm, cnt
        cnt = 1; last = epoch; h=H;  m=M; lh=H; lm=M;
     } else { cnt+=1; lh=H; lm=M; }
  } else { last = epoch; h=H; m=M; lh=H; lm=M; cnt=1; }
  next;
}

END { printf "%s:%s - %s:%s\n%s\n", h, m, lh, lm, cnt }

' ${2:-defaultFileName}
```

For large file inputs, that ought to be a LOT more efficient.

Comment: This will likely be much more efficient if you rewrite the whole thing in `awk`. I think you should be able to use the tools listed [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) for that. If I get time I'll try a POC.